# Facing error while adding document in an envelope via Docusign rest API

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex-code

I am trying to send a document by converting it into base64 string.
The api requires content-length as a require header input. While trying the callout using postman, I am able to make a successful callout as postman calculates the content-length on runtime. But if i change the value to a manual input[any value]. It gives me a read-timout in salesforce/ postman.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to send a DocuSign envelope (signing request) by using Apex.

[This Apex example](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/how-to/send-envelope-with-tabs) shows you how to send an envelope including the addition of a document.

I suggest that you get this example running on your system, then ask a new question in StackOverflow if needed.

This question could have (should) include much more detail on what you were trying and what didn't work.